# Cascading deletes not working when deleting from a 'grouping table'

Tags: mysql, sql

here is a stripped down example of my problem:

I create 2 tables, which are connected via a 'grouping table'.

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    t1_pk INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    t1_entry VARCHAR(150),
    PRIMARY KEY (t1_pk)
) engine = innodb;

CREATE TABLE table2
(
    t2_pk int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    t2_entry VARCHAR(150),
    PRIMARY KEY (t2_pk)
) engine = innodb;

CREATE TABLE grouping
(
    grouping_pk INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    t1_fk INT(11) NOT NULL,
    t2_fk INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (grouping_pk),
    CONSTRAINT table1_fk FOREIGN KEY (t1_fk) REFERENCES table1 (t1_pk) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT table2_fk FOREIGN KEY (t2_fk) REFERENCES table2 (t2_pk) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) engine = innodb;
```

Now I want to delete all the entries from grouping, table1 and table2 where table1.t1_entry is "abc".

I try to do it like this:

```
DELETE FROM grouping
WHERE grouping.grouping_pk IN (SELECT
    temp.entry_id
    FROM (SELECT grouping.grouping_pk,
            grouping.t1_fk,
            grouping.t2_fk,
            table1.t1_pk,
            table1.t1_entry,
            table2.t2_pk,
            table2.t2_entry
            FROM grouping
                LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 ON grouping.t1_fk = table1.t1_pk
                LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON grouping.t2_fk = table2.t2_pk
            WHERE table1.t1_entry LIKE 'abc'
        ) AS temp)
```

As a result, the entries are deleted in the grouping table, but not in table1 and table2.

My question is now, how could I selected records and delete the result set from all tables? I feel like a dummy, because I can't figure this out by myself.

Comment: Deletes only cascade when you delete from the referenced table, not from the referencing table. You're allowed to have items that aren't in any grouping, but you're not allowed to have a grouping that refers to nonexistent items.

Comment: If you want to delete from the other tables when all groupings go away, you need to use a trigger.

Comment: The ON DELETE rule of the foreign key works in the reverse of the way you are thinking about it. With the DELETE rule specified as CASCADE the way you have it... if a row is deleted from **`table1`**, then the associated rows in **`grouping`** will automatically be deleted. Deleting rows from **`grouping`** has no effect on rows in **`table1`**.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen previous questions like this, but I can't find any now.

Comment: @Barmar: I know I've seen this question asked before, but I can't find a duplicate.

Comment: @spencer7593 Yeah, all the words in the searches match so many other questions, because there are so many questions about foreign keys and deleting.

Comment: Note that it doesn't really make sense to say that all items in `table1` and `table2` must be part of a grouping. When you first insert a row into either of these tables, it won't be in a grouping until you insert a corresponding row into the `groupings` table. That's why foreign key dependencies can only go one way. It's not possible to create the rows in all tables simultaneously, something has to be first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing this one now...

Conclusion:
I have to rework my datamodel for a better solution to my problem, based on Barmar and Spencer7593 comments.
Thanks for the much appreciated help!

Answer (score 1):

In grouping table definition of table2_fk you references to table1 instead of table2. It may be that the problem...

Comment: Thank you - that was a typo in the example!